# Global objects in Java?

Tags: java

I have two classes:

```
public class A{
   int money;
   ArrayList<Item> boughtItems;
   .
   .
   public void addBoughtItem(Item item){
      .
      .
   }
   public void adjustMoney(int adjustAmount){
      money = money + adjustamount;
   }
}
```

and another class :

```
public class B{
  ArrayList<Item> itemsForSale;
  .
  .
  public Item sellMeItem(Item item){
    .
    .
    return itemsForSale.get(...);
  }
}
```

Now in the main, I start an instance of class A, and an instance of class B.
inside class B, whenever I sell them an item, I want to update the purchasedItems and adjust the money of the class A instance in realtime (that means, inside the sellMeItem function of class B.)
Therefore I think I need the A instance to be global.
How can I reach the A object that is in the main from inside the class B sellMeItem function? (and class B instance is also in the main)

Comment: pass an instance of A into B via a setter method, or through B's constructor. Store the ref as an instance variable.

Comment: It would be helpful if you named your classes something more descriptive than A and B.  As for globals, I never really think too much in terms of "global" when I work on Java programs.  If you do, you should probably think of that as a "code smell", meaning you're headed in the wrong direction.  What you MAY want is something called the Singleton pattern, though.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: @Marvo A singleton is almost never the solution to the need for a global variable - refactoring is...

Comment: Hence the use of the word "MAY" in my comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Therefore I think I need the A instance to be global.

Not really, you could simply pass a reference to your instance of A to B, for example via a constructor:

```
class B {

    private A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Then you can access `a` in B. And in your main:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a);
```

However, the fact that the 2 classes are so intimately related probably means that the way you have split responsibilities among them is not optimal.

Comment: But when I update the A instance from inside the SellMeItem function in class B, would it update the SAME instance of A that is in the main? Or will it COPY the object and have its own frame?

Comment: I like that last point.  Perhaps break A and B down into lightweight beans, and have a third class that manages the business logic.

Comment: I am so strictly bounded by what my tutors commanded me, I can not split them into two beans and put them in a third class.

Comment: @user1656647 objects are not copied on assignment. What you're assigning is a reference to the object.

Comment: @user1656647 B will hold a reference to the same A instance that you created in your main. So if you write: `a.adjustMoney(123);` in B, it will update the `A` you created in your `main`.

Comment: When you "pass your instance of A to B" you're in reality only passing a reference to A to B.  For B to have its own copy, a copy would need to be created at some point.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply your post was unclear.  References in Java is a concept that's tricky for newbies to pick up, so I was just trying to expand on it.

Comment: @Marvo No problem - I agree with you that it can be confusing.

Comment: Will it work if I added a Setter method in class B and NOT actually include it as a parameter in the constructor of B?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to apply the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) here. Let A subsribe to events on B (you can wire this in the main method).

To do this, you'll probably want to define an interface for observers on B

```
public interface BObserver {

    void itemSold(Item item);

}
```

And have A implement this interface. This way multiple observers of different types can register to B.